# IBM watson image recognition : time taken for training

Tags: image-recognition, watson

How much time does it take to train a classifier in Watson? I uploaded around 500 images and it has been 48 hours and the module is still in training.

I am trying to differentiate plant leaves and thus gave images of plant leaves. Total file size is around 50MB.

Comment: How large are the images?

Comment: @Roope there are about 7-9 classes . and the total size of all classes is around 50MB

Comment: Sometimes a refresh of the page will update the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Training a visual classifier can take some time, due to the upload speeds most people have and the size of the images being used to train the classifier.  Think about how long it would take to transfer the data from the environment that you are working in, to a data center - and that is the absolute quickest that your training will be.

With that being said, I can't imagine that the training would take 24 hours.  With 50MB of data, and 7-9 classes, training should take no longer than a hour at the very most.

Answer (score 1):

Please try retraining the images and there might be some error.
It happened with me many times.
So cancel it and train it again.